# Time series extraction from ghcn data vault

Tags: database, time-series, extract, text-extraction

This link has several datas

http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/gsn/ASN00014508.dly

I wanted to extract daily precipitation time series for all the years

ASN00014508196703PRCP the name of each rows represents various information such as prcp AT THE END REPRESENTS ITS A precipitation data thats is what i need to extaract.then 03 represents month,and 1967 represents year .

Can anyone extract time series for this station I tried but was unsuccessful in all attempts.

Comment: Is there a dataset documentation link you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at their [API](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2) to extract the data you need?